# More efficient way to clean a column of strings and add a new column

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have a dataframe `df` that has the columns `['metric_type', 'metric_value']`.  For each row, I want to make sure I have a column with the name equal to `'metric_type'` and a value for that column equal to `'metric_value'`.

One of my problems is that `'metric_type'` has spurious spaces that I want to get rid of.

Consider the dataframe `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a ', 1],
        [' b', 2],
        [' c ', 3]
    ], columns=['metric_type', 'metric_value'])

print(df)

  metric_type  metric_value
0          a              1
1           b             2
2          c              3
```

Notice that each value of `'metric_type'` has spaces in varying places.

I created a function to use `apply` but it takes a horribly long time.

```
def assign_metric_vals(row):
    row[row['metric_type'].replace(" ", "")] = row['metric_value']
    return row
```

When I use it, I get this:

```
       a    b    c metric_type  metric_value
0 1.0000  nan  nan          a              1
1    nan 2.00  nan           b             2
2    nan  nan 3.00          c              3
```

Is there a better (read, "faster") way to accomplish this same task?

Comment: `apply` is inherently slow. It is basically a wrapper around a python-for-loop.

Comment: Anyway, it seems like whatever you are trying to accomplish should be able to be done with basic `pandas` assignment. Why don't you describe what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: If it were that simple, I would not have posted this question. Apologies if there is misunderstanding in what I'm trying to accomplish. There is a column metric_type that contains values that I converted into columns. I then need to assign the metric_value columns rows to the proper converted metric_type columns.

Comment: Added clarification at the bottom. Thanks though.

Comment: How about `df['metric_type'] = [x.strip() for x in df.metric_type]` ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're much better served setting your index with `metric_type` and unstacking.

```
df.set_index(df.metric_type.str.replace(' ', ''), append=True).metric_value.unstack()
```

---

***demonstration***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['a ', 1],
        [' b', 2],
        [' c ', 3]
    ], columns=['metric_type', 'metric_value'])

print(df)

  metric_type  metric_value
0          a              1
1           b             2
2          c              3

print(df.apply(assign_metric_vals, 1))

       a    b    c metric_type  metric_value
0 1.0000  nan  nan          a              1
1    nan 2.00  nan           b             2
2    nan  nan 3.00          c              3
```

---

***or my way***

```
idx = df.metric_type.str.replace(' ', '')
d1 = df.set_index(idx, append=True).metric_value.unstack()
print(pd.concat([d1, df], axis=1))

       a    b    c metric_type  metric_value
0 1.0000  nan  nan          a              1
1    nan 2.00  nan           b             2
2    nan  nan 3.00          c              3
```

***timing***

use a bigger `df`
`df1 = pd.concat([df] * 30000, ignore_index=True)`

```
%%timeit
idx = df1.metric_type.str.replace(' ', '')
d1 = df1.set_index(idx, append=True).metric_value.unstack()
pd.concat([d1, df1], axis=1)
```

> 10 loops, best of 3: 77.3 ms per loop

```
%%timeit
df1.apply(assign_metric_vals, 1)
```

> 1 loop, best of 3: 57.4 s per loop

Comment: np, vote on my new question and answer.  I posted that question from the phone app.

Comment: upvote on the question is what I needed.  Hopefully numpy people will like it

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that is about 20% faster and gives the same answer as @piRSquared's.  I wouldn't suggest that it's either better or worse (in general), but the bounty was posted after that answer was accepted so I'll offer this as an additional option.

```
%%timeit
idx = df1.metric_type.str.replace(' ', '')
d1 = df1.set_index(idx, append=True).metric_value.unstack()
result1 = pd.concat([d1, df1], axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 97.6 ms per loop

%%timeit 
df1.metric_type = df1.metric_type.str.strip()
d1 = df1.pivot(columns='metric_type', values='metric_value')
result2 = pd.concat([d1, df1], axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 77.2 ms per loop
```

About 1/3 of the speed improvement is from using `strip` instead of `replace` and 2/3 from using `pivot` instead of `unstack`.  (The `concat` step is the same and extremely fast anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the way in which the final dataframe gets created, one-hot-encoding of the string column doesn't seem like a bad idea indeed in terms of it's overall performance when compared to the other approaches mentioned so far.

***Steps:***

1. Using `pd.get_dummies` on `metric_type` series, create dummy variables from categorical ones. This part coupled with `str.strip` is the most time consuming of the lot.
2. Instead of stripping leading/trailing whitespace characters directly on the series object, we could finish off with computing the `get_dummies` portion as there are high chances that some of the categorical variables do get repeated in the series which later would share the same column during dummy creation. The more the duplicated variables, the lesser the time spent on filtering off those extra spaces. Perform `str.strip` only on the obtained columns of the dummy variable `DF`. This approach is a huge time saver.
3. Sort these columns obtained so that they are lexicographically sorted and the duplicated ones(if present) would be placed adjacent to one another. Allow the `DF` to be modified according to these combination of columns.
4. Make use of `np.unique` with `return_index=True` parameter to extract the unique columns present and also it's corresponding indices.
5. We need to find a way to group the identical columns into a single wholesome column. For this, we can use `np.add.reduceat` which works similar to a `groupby` operation (equivalent - `df.groupby(df.columns.tolist(), axis=1).sum()`) but has it's specialty in being really fast. The indices to be paired are supplied by `idx` of `np.unique`.The reduction of the values occur at these slices and their running sum gets computed across columns(`axis=1`).
6. The `dtype` returned is `bool` which helps us in using `np.where` as it functions like a boolean mask wherein 1's/0's get mapped to `True`/`False` respectively. These 1's are then filled by values residing in `metric_value` series and 0's by `NaN`.
7. Our `DF` is ready now which needs to be concatenated with the original starting `DF` columnwise resulting in the final cleaned dataframe.

---

***Solution:***

```
def dummies_strip_concat(df):
    one_hot_enc = pd.get_dummies(df.metric_type)
    one_hot_enc.columns = one_hot_enc.columns.str.strip()
    one_hot_enc.sortlevel(axis=1, inplace=True)
    a, idx = np.unique(one_hot_enc.columns.values, return_index=True)
    out = np.where(np.add.reduceat(one_hot_enc.values, idx, axis=1, dtype=np.bool), 
                   df.metric_value.values[:, None], 
                   np.nan)
    return (pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(out, df.index, a), df], axis=1))
```

---

***Timings:***

```
def pir(df):
    idx = df.metric_type.str.replace(' ', '')
    d1 = df.set_index(idx, append=True).metric_value.unstack()
    return pd.concat([d1, df], axis=1)

def johne(df):
    df.metric_type = df.metric_type.str.strip()
    d1 = df.pivot(columns='metric_type', values='metric_value')
    return pd.concat([d1, df], axis=1)
```

For a `DF` containing few thousand rows comparable to what OP had in mind:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df] * 30000, ignore_index=True)
df1.shape
(90000, 2)

# Check whether they produce the same outcome
dummies_strip_concat(df1).equals(pir(df1))
True

%timeit pir(df1)
10 loops, best of 3: 97.5 ms per loop

%timeit johne(df1)
10 loops, best of 3: 76.5 ms per loop

%timeit dummies_strip_concat(df1)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Very nice solution.

Comment: Thanks! Took me a while to arrive at this. Maybe you can come up with some of your newly learnt `numpy` techniques and better mine. Have a wonderful year ahead!

Comment: I just enjoy getting people involved and learning other's techniques. Happy New Year to you as well.

Comment: Step 2 is pretty smart. Following up that same logic, do you get any gain or loss by converting `metric_type` to categorical before applying get_dummies? Just curious if it has any impact. thanks.

Comment: Good thought! Type casting it to categorical dtype via `astype('category')` or even creating a new categorical variable altogether using `pd.Categorical(values=df.metric_type.tolist())` has little to no effect on the execution speed when tested on this dataset as it lingers very close(only change in the decimal point) to what was got before. In my opinion, the only advantage of changing the series to categorical type would be to minimize the memory usage especially when there are fewer number of categories compared to the entire series length. But that is only an assumption here.

Comment: @piRSquared, Thanks for granting me the bounty and it's much appreciated :-) I suppose maybe if you had waited till the entire duration or tagged this post under `numpy`, someone else might have come up with a better answer ;-)

Comment: @piRSquared, I really liked the pictorial illustration of the question and also glanced through the answer which I felt was nicely explained. I'm not that well-versed with `numpy` so can't give you an instant feedback unless I've assimilated those minute details. But anyways you've set such high standards for yourself, so I've upvoted.

Comment: @NickilMaveli tyvm